# Approximation of $1-e^{-z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, approximation-theory

I am interested in approximating the function $1-e^{-z}$. I want to approximate it by a family of functions $f_n$ that are entire and $f_n(2\pi k i) = 0$ for all $2\pi k i$ with $|k|\le n$ and $f_n(2\pi k i) \ne 0$ for all $2\pi k i$ with $|k|> n$. Is this possible?

When I say that the sequence $f_n$ approximates $1-e^{-z}$, I mean that there exists a sequence of functions as described and an open set $D$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(z) = 1-e^{-z}$ uniformly in $D$.

So far I have succeeded only on the second part.

We have that for any $z$ such that the left hand side makes sense, it holds that
$$ \frac{1}{1-e^{-z}} = \frac12+\frac1z + \sum_{k\ge0}\frac{2z}{z^2+4\pi^2 k^2}.$$
So if we define
$$ f_n(z) = \frac12+\frac1z + \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2z}{z^2+4\pi^2 k^2} $$
then clearly
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(z) = \frac{1}{1-e^{-z}}. $$

This implies that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{f_n(z)} = 1-e^{-z}. $$

However these functions have poles which do not seem to escape to infinity as $n\to\infty$, so I cannot really use them.

EDIT: As WimC noted, given my requirements, $1-e^{-z}$ is a good approximation of itself, so I changed it to what I actually need.

EDIT2: The solution to this is given by the Weierstraß product theorem, as suggested by Daniel Fischer. We get
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-\frac{s}{2}}s \prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{s^2}{4\pi^2 k^2}\right) = 1-e^{-s}. $$

Comment: The problem is exactly the type that the Weierstraß product theorem handles well.

Comment: $1-e^{-z}$ is a pretty good entire approximation.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for rational functions rather than entire functions?

Comment: @WimC you are right. I changed a bit the question.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I don't mind rational functions, as long as their poles eventually escape to infinity.

Comment: @DanielFischer you are right! It is the solution. You can write it as an answer if you wish.